# URL: transform "/news.php?id=1" to "/news/1/"

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to make some more cleaner URL's for my website. I have allready found lots of questions regarding the removal of file extensions in URL's and managed to get that working. I want to take it a step further though by transforming an URL like **http://www.site.com/news.php?id=1** into **http://www.site.com/news/1/**. I couldn't find an answer to this specific question so I'm asking it here. How could I achieve URL's like that?

Rewrite rules I allready have in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(([A-Za-z0-9\-]+/)*[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)?$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of questions out there that answer your question. There are two things you have to do:

1. Redirect the ugly url to the fancy url, so that the user sees the fancy url
2. Internally rewrite the fancy url to the ugly url, so that the server can actually execute it.

You can find the documentation for mod_rewrite [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). This solution uses the `[END]` flag which is only available from Apache 2.3.9 and up. You can find the documentation [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end). The trailing `?` in the first rule discards the query string.

```
#Redirect ugly url to fancy url
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^news\.php$ news/%1/? [R]

#Internally rewrite fancy url to a usable url
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]*)/?$ news.php?id=$1 [END]
```